# Can a born Jamaican with American citizenship book a one way flight to Jamaica

Tags: dual-nationality, jamaica, jamaican-citizens

A born Jamaican lady, who is also a US citizen was recently prevented from boarding a Southwest flight from the USA to Jamaica because of not having a return ticket to the USA. This lady had traveled from the USA to Jamaica on many occasions on  one-way tickets via Southwest and other airlines and it was never an issue.  Is Southwest acting on a new policy?

Comment: Do you also have a Jamaican passport? Without that, it's [Jamaica's immigration policy](http://www.congenjamaica-ny.org/visas/requirements-2/) that requires a round trip ticket to enter, not the airline. The airline adheres to a government's entry requirements and will not board a passenger without those (or face penalties, fees and the costs of returning the passenger).

Answer (score 4):

> Is Southwest acting on a new policy?

I don't know whether Southwest or Jamaica has changed policy recently, but Southwest should be expected to treat someone who shows (only) a US passport as a US citizen.  The Jamaican consulate in New York [notes](http://www.congenjamaica-ny.org/visas/requirements-2/) that visitors must "be in possession of a return or round trip ticket to another country to which they are admissible."

Now, a Jamaican immigration officer might recognize this traveler as a Jamaican citizen, but it's not reasonable to expect a relatively low-level employee of an airline to reach the same conclusion unless the traveler shows a Jamaican passport.  Countries typically fine airlines when a passenger is refused entry unless the airline can show that the passenger presented adequate documents.  The amount of the fine is typically in the range of a few thousand US dollars or equivalent.  The lack of a round-trip ticket in this case leaves Southwest at risk of a fine.

The obvious advice for the traveler in question is to get a Jamaican  passport.  If she did in fact have and show a Jamaican passport in this case, then the advice would be to complain to Southwest and seek compensation.